# Trigger website-eastereggs on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have a website and I thought it would be funny to build in some eastereggs.
So I implemented a konami-code easteregg. 
But there are no possibility to trigger this on mobile devices.

Do you know a way to trigger something on a mobile device but only when you know how (users shouldn't discover this by accident)?

Comment: You could use frameworks such as Bootstrap 3/4 or Foundation 6. They have several visibility classes where you can hide elements on desktop, but shown on mobile. Otherwise you could do it with media queries. Bootstrap visibility classes - http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/ (This is for bootstrap 4), Foundation visibility classes - http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/visibility.html

Answer (score 0):

You could make an "cheat code" input field, make that hidden on a specific width (desktop) and shown on other width (mobile)

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="cheatcode" id="cheatcode">
```

CSS

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    #cheatcode{display: block}
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    #cheatcode{display: none}
}
```

So than when they enter some code in there you could have it do all trippy stuff :)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Konami Cheagg 3000 - version 0.15

**instruction book**

1. double click `footer` to load control pad
2. enter konami code

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/7cv2yxg4/15/

needs a lot of work, let me know if it works on mobile.

Comment: I think that would be an overkill